# WebDav PROPFIND always giving same result

Tags: curl, webdav

I've tried the following command:

```
curl -u username:pass -X PROPFIND "http://cloud.vantibolli.com/remote.php/webdav/PRODUCTION%20SUBS/"
```

It always gives me the same result if property exist or not:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://cloud.vantibolli.com/remote.php/webdav/PRODUCTION%20SUBS/VAN%20TIBOLLI%20LTD%20-%20IRELAND/2016/Expenses/July/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at cloud.vantibolli.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Comment: The url you are using redirects to https. Follow the redirect